# Internal Server Error (Heroku Console)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, session-cookies

Good day guys i'm having a problem about the cookie session im making. I want to get rid of the error

> connect.session() memorystore is not designed for a production environment

so i've red a forum that says it's normal and if i want to get rid of the error then use a connect-redis and yeah it works but the problem is it gives me an error when opening my app(not in the console);

> Internal Server Error

and on my console its returning the

```
return next(new Error('Oh no')) //handle error
```

Here is my code so far:

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

```
app.use(session({
cookie:{
    secure: true,
    maxAge:60000
       },
store: new RedisStore({host:'https://pektos6.herokuapp.com', port: port}),
secret: 'secret',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: false
}));

app.use(function(req,res,next){
if(!req.session){
    return next(new Error('Oh no')) //handle error
}
next() //otherwise continue
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did here is

```
var session = require('cookie-session'); 
//instead of
//var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false
    cookie:{secure:true}
}));
```

and the memory leak is gone